# unable to debug spring boot application with postman requests

Tags: spring-boot, maven, debugging, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij latest version. I have a Spring Boot application which I do execute application by maven goals : spring-boot run in debug mode. The application started without any problem but unfortunately I am not able to debug the application hen I send request from Postman. I can see the logs and I can see my requests/responses are working properly.

But I am not able to debug it .. Mvn clean/install, maven compile all the commands are working properly except debugging.

You know how to fix that problem ?

Comment: Have you tried running debug mode from Application.class in intellij?

Comment: I did it but it gave me different errors such like. Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).